# Normalization words for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm currently doing sentiment analysis and having a problem.

I have a big normalization for word and I want to normalization text before tokenize like this example:

| data | normal |
| --- | --- |
| kamu knp sayang | kamu kenapa sayang |
| drpd sedih mending belajar | dari pada sedih mending belajar |
| dmna sekarang | di mana sekarang |

- knp: kenapa
- drpd: dari pada
- dmna: di mana

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

slang = pd.DataFrame({'before': ['knp', 'dmna', 'drpd'], 'after': ['kenapa', 'di mana', 'dari pada']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['kamu knp sayang', 'drpd sedih mending bermain']})
                  
normalisasi = {}

for index, row in slang.iterrows():
  if row[0] not in normalisasi:
    normalisasi[row[0]] = row[1]


def normalized_term(document):
    return [normalisasi[term] if term in normalisasi else term for term in document]

df['normal'] = df['data'].apply(normalized_term)
df
```

But, the result like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCpCB.png)

I want the result like the example table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility named `str.replace` in pandas that allows us to replace a substring with another or even find/replace patterns. You can find full documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). Your desired output would have appeared like this:

**UPDATE**

There were two things wrong with the answer:

1. You must only replace in `whole word` mode, not `subword`
2. After each entry in the slang file you must `keep the changes` not discard them

---

So it would be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data bersih.xlsx')
slang = pd.read_excel('slang.xlsx')
df['normal'] = df.text
for idx, row in slang.iterrows():
    df['normal'] = df.normal.str.replace(r"\b"+row['before']+r"\b", row['after'], regex=True)
```

output:

```
                                                   text  \
0                           hari ini udh mulai ppkm yaa   
1     mohon info apakah pgs pasar turi selama ppkm b...   
2     di rumah aja soalnya lagi ppkm entah bakal nga...   
3     pangkal penanganan pandemi di indonesia yang t...   
4                              ppkm mikro anjingggggggg   
...                                                 ...   
9808  drpd nonton sinetron mending bagi duit kayak g...   
9809                     ppkm pelan pelan kalau masukin   
9810  masih ada kepala desa camat bahkan kepala daer...   
9811            aku suka ppkm tapi tanpa pp di depannya   
9812  menteri ini perlu tidak dibayarkan gajinya set...   

                                                 normal  
0                         hari ini sudah mulai ppkm yaa  
1     mohon informasi apakah pgs pasar turi selama p...  
2     di rumah saja soalnya lagi ppkm entah bakal se...  
3     pangkal penanganan pandemi di indonesia yang t...  
4                              ppkm mikro anjingggggggg  
...                                                 ...  
9808  dari pada nonton sinema elektronik lebih baik ...  
9809                    ppkm pelan pelan kalau masukkan  
9810  masih ada kepala desa camat bahkan kepala daer...  
9811  aku suka ppkm tapi tanpa pulang pergi di depannya  
9812  menteri ini perlu tidak dibayarkan gajinya set...  

[9813 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Your code is working well but, can't normalize all my data. If I look my data after normalize, some data are normalized and some are not. I don't know why.

Comment: Please add the `slang` and the `df` in which we would face the error! @teapartyyyy

Comment: [after normalize](https://imgur.com/a/q6LnxHp) You can see in row number 0 the word 'udh' which should 'sudah' is not normalize. And you can see in row number 9808 the word 'drpd' which should 'dari pada' is correct. I put `slang` data in Excel [slang.xlsx](https://imgur.com/a/bYpY5IC)

Comment: Please double-check for typos. I couldn't figure out what happened! Add your slang and data in the form I can copy/paste.  Another thing that might happen is the source strings contains special chars with the same appearance but different Unicode! @teapartyyyy

Comment: here [github](https://github.com/jovanap17/Sentimen-Analysis)

Comment: I updated the answer @teapartyyyy, check it out ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me. :)